# How do I add a revisions tab to a custom content entity to list revisions?

Tags: 8, entities

I've just created/generated a custom content entity module using Drush. I've checked I would like to use revisions, but I cannot see its tab.

How can I add the revisions tab to this custom content entity and list revisions for that entity instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I show the annotation used from the [`\Drupal\node\Entity\Node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/class/Node/8.9.x) class to make clear which keys need to be used and as example of values to assign to those keys.)

Similarly to what done with nodes, the entity class annotation needs to:

1. Declare the revision tables

```php
/**
  *   revision_table = "node_revision",
  *   revision_data_table = "node_field_revision",
  */
```

2. Tell Drupal to show the revision UI

```php
/**
  *   show_revision_ui = TRUE,
  */
```

3. Tell Drupal which fields in the database match the revision entity fields

```php
/**
  *   entity_keys = {
  *     "id" = "nid",
  *     "revision" = "vid",
  *     "bundle" = "type",
  *     "label" = "title",
  *     "langcode" = "langcode",
  *     "uuid" = "uuid",
  *     "status" = "status",
  *     "published" = "status",
  *     "uid" = "uid",
  *     "owner" = "uid",
  *   },
  *   revision_metadata_keys = {
  *     "revision_user" = "revision_uid",
  *     "revision_created" = "revision_timestamp",
  *     "revision_log_message" = "revision_log"
  *   },
  */
```

4. In the *links* section, tell Drupal which links are for the revisions

```php
/**
  *   links = {
  *     "canonical" = "/node/{node}",
  *     "delete-form" = "/node/{node}/delete",
  *     "delete-multiple-form" = "/admin/content/node/delete",
  *     "edit-form" = "/node/{node}/edit",
  *     "version-history" = "/node/{node}/revisions",
  *     "revision" = "/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/view",
  *     "create" = "/node",
  *   }
  */
```

Note that in the third step, defining the *revision_metadata_keys* values isn't optional, for an entity type that supports revisions. This is made clear in the [Revision metadata fields are now defined in the entity annotation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2831499) change record.

> `ContentEntityTypeInterface::getRevisionMetadataKeys()` has a parameter for backwards compatibility to search for the revision metadata field names through the base field definitions but as of Drupal 9.0.0 it will be removed and the revision metadata keys will have to be explicitly defined in the entity annotation.
> That same change record contains a link to [Converting a content entity type to be revisionable and publishable](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/converting-a-content-entity-type-to-be-revisionable-and-publishable), which is now outdated and it suggests to read [Support for automatic entity updates has been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742) for the most current information on the topic.

The module implementing the entity must define the routes used for the revision pages. The Node module does it in the [node.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.routing.yml/8.9.x) file, but the *route_provider* class (which implements [`EntityRouteProviderInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Routing%21EntityRouteProviderInterface.php/interface/EntityRouteProviderInterface/8.9.x)) could define them too.

```yaml
entity.node.version_history:
  path: '/node/{node}/revisions'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Revisions'
    _controller: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::revisionOverview'
  requirements:
    _access_node_revision: 'view'
    node: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE

entity.node.revision:
  path: '/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/view'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::revisionShow'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::revisionPageTitle'
  requirements:
    _access_node_revision: 'view'
    node: \d+

node.revision_revert_confirm:
  path: '/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/revert'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\node\Form\NodeRevisionRevertForm'
    _title: 'Revert to earlier revision'
  requirements:
    _access_node_revision: 'update'
    node: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE

node.revision_revert_translation_confirm:
  path: '/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/revert/{langcode}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\node\Form\NodeRevisionRevertTranslationForm'
    _title: 'Revert to earlier revision of a translation'
  requirements:
    _access_node_revision: 'update'
    node: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE

node.revision_delete_confirm:
  path: '/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/delete'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\node\Form\NodeRevisionDeleteForm'
    _title: 'Delete earlier revision'
  requirements:
    _access_node_revision: 'delete'
    node: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
```

The entity class should also extend [`EditorialContentEntityBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EditorialContentEntityBase.php/class/EditorialContentEntityBase/8.9.x), a base entity class with extended revision and publishing support. Using it, adding the revision and publishing fields is simple as adding `$fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);` to the `baseFieldDefinitions()` method of the entity class.

Comment: Thank you very much @kiamlaluno! :)

Answer (score 1):

After reading apaderno's answer and 2 days of research and development I figured out that some important steps are missing, in my opinion.

Therefor I made a more detailed walkthrough. This contains part of apaderno's answer and much parts and copy and past of some code of the node module.

I was using Drupal 9.3 to approach this.

## How to get a revision view of a custom content entity

### Create a Storage-Class for your Entity

Create your Storage-Class like so:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;


use Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

class CustomEntityStorage extends
  SqlContentEntityStorage implements
  CustomEntityStorageInterface
{

  /*
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function revisionIds(CustomEntityInterface $myEntity)
  {
    return $this->database->query(
      'SELECT [vid] FROM {' . $this->getRevisionTable() . '} WHERE [nid] = :nid ORDER BY [vid]',
      [':nid' => $myEntity->id()]
    )->fetchCol();
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function userRevisionIds(AccountInterface $account) {
    return $this->database->query(
      'SELECT [vid] FROM {' . $this->getRevisionDataTable() . '} WHERE [uid] = :uid ORDER BY [vid]',
      [':uid' => $account->id()]
    )->fetchCol();
  }
}
```

The corresponding interface:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageInterface;

interface CustomEntityStorageInterface extends ContentEntityStorageInterface
{
  /**
   * Gets a list of node revision IDs for a specific node.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\my_module\CustomEntityInterface $myEntity
   *   The node entity.
   *
   * @return int[]
   *   Node revision IDs (in ascending order).
   */
  public function revisionIds(CustomEntityInterface $myEntity);
}
```

Then add this storage class in the handlers section of the custom entity class annotation:

```php
...
 handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\my_module\CustomEntityStorage",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\my_module\CustomEntityListBuilder",
 ...
```

### Create a Controller for handling the revision view

You can create the controller class by using drush:

```bash
drush generate controller
```

Give it the name you wish and add these services:

- renderer
- date formatter
- entity repository

Then add the method which should render the revision page like so. A lot of this is copied from the node module

```php
/**
   * Generates an overview table of older revisions of a node.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\emp\CustomEntityInterface $myEntity
   *   A node object.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array as expected by \Drupal\Core\Render\RendererInterface::render().
   */
  public function revisionOverview(CustomEntityInterface $myEntity) {
    $langcode = $myEntity->language()->getId();
    $langname = $myEntity->language()->getName();
    $languages = $myEntity->getTranslationLanguages();
    $has_translations = (count($languages) > 1);
    $myEntityStorage = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('MY_ENTITY_ID'); // see "id" in ContentEntityType annotation of you entity

    $build['#title'] = $has_translations ? $this->t('@langname revisions for %title', ['@langname' => $langname, '%title' => $myEntity->label()]) : $this->t('Revisions for %title', ['%title' => $myEntity->label()]);
    $header = [$this->t('Revision'), $this->t('Operations')];

    $rows = [];
    $default_revision = $myEntity->getRevisionId();
    $current_revision_displayed = FALSE;
    $revisions = $this->getRevisionIds($myEntity, $myEntityStorage);

    foreach ($revisions as $vid) {
      /** @var \Drupal\my_module\CustomEntityInterface $revision */
      $revision = $myEntityStorage->loadRevision($vid);
      // Only show revisions that are affected by the language that is being
      // displayed.
      if (TRUE) {
        $username = [
          '#theme' => 'username',
          '#account' => $revision->getRevisionUser(),
        ];

        // Use revision link to link to revisions that are not active.
        $date = $this->dateFormatter->format($revision->revision_timestamp->value, 'short');

        // We treat also the latest translation-affecting revision as current
        // revision, if it was the default revision, as its values for the
        // current language will be the same of the current default revision in
        // this case.
        $is_current_revision = $vid == $default_revision || (!$current_revision_displayed && $revision->wasDefaultRevision());
        if (!$is_current_revision) {
          /*
          you can add link - example from node module
          $link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($date, new Url('entity.node.revision', ['node' => $node->id(), 'node_revision' => $vid]))->toString();
          */
        }
        else {
          $link = $myEntity->toLink($date)->toString();
          $current_revision_displayed = TRUE;
        }

        $row = [];
        $column = [
          'data' => [
            '#type' => 'inline_template',
            '#template' => '{% trans %}{{ date }} by {{ username }}{% endtrans %}{% if message %}<p class="revision-log">{{ message }}</p>{% endif %}',
            '#context' => [
              'date' => "RevisionId: $vid at $date",
              'username' => $this->renderer->renderPlain($username),
              'message' => ['#markup' => $revision->revision_log->value, '#allowed_tags' => Xss::getHtmlTagList()],
            ],
          ],
        ];
        // @todo Simplify once https://www.drupal.org/node/2334319 lands.
        $this->renderer->addCacheableDependency($column['data'], $username);
        $row[] = $column;

        if ($is_current_revision) {
          $row[] = [
            'data' => [
              '#prefix' => '<em>',
              '#markup' => $this->t('Current revision'),
              '#suffix' => '</em>',
            ],
          ];

          $rows[] = [
            'data' => $row,
            'class' => ['revision-current'],
          ];
        }
        else {
          $links = [];
          $row[] = [
            'data' => [
              '#type' => 'operations',
              '#links' => $links,
            ],
          ];

          $rows[] = $row;
        }
      }
    }

    $build['node_revisions_table'] = [
      '#theme' => 'table',
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#header' => $header,
      '#attributes' => ['class' => 'node-revision-table'],
    ];

    $build['pager'] = ['#type' => 'pager'];

    return $build;
  }
```

You can customize this that it meet your requirements. This is just an example

### Add routing

extend the my_module.routing.yml file like so:

```yaml
my_module.my_entity.version_history:
  path: '/admin/my_entity/{myEntity}/revisions'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Revisions'
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyEntityController::revisionOverview'
  options:
    parameters:
      myEntity:
        type: entity:MY_ENTITY_ID
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    myEntity: \d+
```

Important note: the name of the parameter in the curly brackets in path HAS TO MATCH the name of the parameter in the function you are calling to render - in this example:

Parameter name `myEntity` is used as parameter name in function `revisionOverview`

### add task

now you can add a task which should make a tab appear on you entity page.
Extend the my_module.links.task.yml file like so:

```yaml
my_module.my_entity.revisions:
  route_name: my_module.my_entity.version_history
  base_route: my_module.my_entity.canonical
  title: 'Revisions'
```